$X$ connected and $A \subseteq M \setminus X$ is clopen then $(A \cup X )$ is connected
Proposition:
Let  $M$  be a connected metric space,  $X \subset M$  a connected subset, and  $A \subseteq M \setminus X $ such that  $A$ is clopen in  $M \setminus X$ . Prove that $ A \cup X $ is connected.
I decide to try to prove by contradiction assuming that it is  $ A \cup X $ disconnected. Using the assumption that $X$ is connected I conclude that $X$ must be completely contained in $U$ or $V$ . Therefore $A$ will be contained in the opposite but I don't know what to do from here to conclude then that $A$ will not be clopen in $M \setminus X$ . (In this case $U$ and $V$ are the disjoint open sets in which it arises when assuming that  $ A \cup X $ it is disconnected.)

What is $M-X$ ? Has this anything to do with the real numbers?

@Tina This notation is sometimes used instead of $\setminus$. I've seen it in some books.

@Tina M-X=M\X . If A is contained in M-X, this means that it does not have any element in common with X.

Yes, this holds in arbitrary topological spaces, see here, lemma 8 (page 10). ($T_1$ is not needed in the proof.)

Your first step is correct. Namely, let $U$ and $V$ be open sets of $M$ such that $(X\cup A)\cap U$ and $(X\cup A)\cap V$ partition $X\cup A$. Without loss of generality assume that $X\subseteq U$. I do not believe you can assume $U$ and $V$ to be disjoint.
We have that $A\setminus U=A\cap V$ is clopen in $X\cup A$, if we show that $A\cap V$ is clopen in $M$ we are done since $M$ is connected.
Since $A$ is clopen in $M\setminus X$, there exist an open set $W$ and a closed set $C$ of $M$ such that $W\setminus X=C\setminus X=A$. We note that $W,C\subseteq (X\cup A)$.
Since $V\cap X=\emptyset$ we have that have that $W\cap V=A\cap V$ and so $A\cap V$ is an open set. Similarly, we have that since $X\subseteq U$, and therefore $X\cap(M\setminus U)=\emptyset$ that $(M\setminus U)\cap C=A\cap(M\setminus U)=A\setminus U=A\cap V$ is a closed. So $A\cap V$ is clopen in $M$ and so it must be empty. This proves that $X\cup A$ only has trivial clopen sets and therefore is connected.
Note: The argument is purely topological so it work for non metrizable spaces as well.
